# Windows recognizes Home Theater receiver as a display

Tags: windows-7, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've bought a Yamaha receiver, A2050. I connect my PC on it using HDMI, from my CPU Haswell i5-4590.

Audio is sent perfectly to it, but Windows believes it's a display and added it as a monitor.

Is there any config or app that makes Windows send audio in that HDMI, but not recognize it as a display and not send video to it?

Comment: can you disable the display component in Device Manager?

Comment: Try this : Disable the monitor it tries to create, right-click on the volume icon and select Playback devices, right click HDMI out and select as default device.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late feedback. I ended up changing my monitors layout and now the same HDMI is used for video and audio, so I don't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the display settings/screen resolution portion of the Control Panel, you can select the not-a-display, then, from the "Multiple displays" dropdown you can choose "Disconnect this display".

Comment: That’s not what the question is (literally) asking for. It does prevent the mouse from disappearing “off-screen” though.

Comment: @DanielB I don't think there's a way to make Windows not recognize it as a video device in the first place if the receiver advertises itself as such. You're right that it doesn't 100% answer the question as stated, but I think it matches the overall goal and is easier than spelunking through the device manager.